# Giving div a none rectangular shape

Tags: html, css, transform

I want to give a div none rectangular shape (look at the image below to see, how div should look). I've tried several transforms, but couldn't achieve the desired result. Here is a code snippet

```css
.container {
  height: 60px;
  background: #252b33;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.tab {
  background: #3b424b;
  height: 40px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 50px
}
.tab1 {
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
}
.tab2 {
  transform: rotateX(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab"></div>
  <div class="tab tab1"></div>
  <div class="tab tab2"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

My question is: How can I give a div shape shown in the image using CSS?

Comment: please add your code and show us what you tried so far

Comment: transform: skewX(-45deg); gave the best result, however left and right sides still were parallel

Comment: I mean show your relavant html with css code in snnipet(edit your question)

Comment: rotateX didn't change angles of sides

Comment: I added a code snippet

Comment: Did you try using SVG?

Comment: No I didn't. I think a sollution with div would be much better, but if it's impossible, I guess the only way will be to use an svg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use css as below to `.tab`

```
border-bottom: 40px solid #555;
border-left: 20px solid transparent;
border-right: 20px solid transparent;
```

See here:

```css
.container {
  height: 60px;
  background: #252b33;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.tab {
  height: 40px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 0px;
  border-bottom: 40px solid #555;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab"></div>
  <div class="tab tab1"></div>
  <div class="tab tab2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help:)